# Django forms.ModelChoiceField queryset problem with models.manager

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am having trouble making a ModelChoiceField queryset in a ModelForm. The related model.objects manager has been overridden to filter the results in order to get only instances created by the actual user. Here are my models :

```
class Bloc(ModelPrive):
    TYPE_BLOC = (
        ('pleinchamps', 'plein champs'),
        ('tunnel', 'tunnel'),
        ('pepiniere', 'pépinière'),
        ('autre', 'autre'),
    )
    nb_planche = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    caracteristique = models.CharField(max_length=200, null= True, blank=True)
    geom = models.PolygonField(srid=4326)
    type_bloc = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, choices=TYPE_BLOC)
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, unique= True)


class ModelPrive(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True,  on_delete=models.SET_NULL, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    objects = ModelPriveManager()


class ModelPriveManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_current_user()
        return super().get_queryset().filter(created_by=user)
```

In my manager the get_current_user() returns the actual user that has been intercepted by a custom middleware.

Here is my form :

```
class BlocFormList(ModelForm):
    choix_bloc = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Bloc.objects.all().order_by('nom'), required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Bloc
        fields = ['choix_bloc']
```

Here is my view :

```
def planification(request):
    form_bloc = BlocFormList()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # some other code

    return render(request, 'planification.html', locals())
```

The problem is, when I do a Bloc.objects.all() in views I get the expected answer (Bloc.objects.filter(created_by=user)) but when it is done inside the queryset of the modelform, it returns nothing (as if there were no active user).

After some checks, I have found that the model form queryset doesn't even go into the manager.

If someone knows how to correct this, I have no more ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing this post [Django ModelForm overriding __init__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270099/django-modelform-overriding-init), I finally found my solution by overriding the **init** of my ModelForm :

```
class BlocFormList(ModelForm):

    blocs = None
    choix_bloc = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='Blocs', queryset=blocs, required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.blocs = Bloc.objects.all()
        super(BlocFormList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['choix_bloc'].queryset = self.blocs

    class Meta:
        model = Bloc
        fields = ['choix_bloc']
```

This works fine.